# Delete path, not entire array

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to delete a file out of a tableview that is populated by Apple's sample code DirectoryWatcher and DITableViewController. Here is my code, I seem to be deleting the entire array rather than an individual file.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
        [documentURLs removeObjectAtIndex:row];      
    }

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *pathToDocumentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToDocumentsDirectory];
    NSLog(@"Path to file: %@", pathToDocumentsDirectory);        
    NSLog(@"File exists: %d", fileExists);
    NSLog(@"Is deletable file at path: %d", [fileManager isDeletableFileAtPath:pathToDocumentsDirectory]);
    if (fileExists) 
    {
        BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:pathToDocumentsDirectory
                                               error:&error];
        if (!success) 
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out how to just delete a single file out of the array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code attempts to delete the app's Documents directory.

You need to pull the URL out of the `documentURLs` array and pass that to `-[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:]`.  For example:

```
NSURL *urlToDelete = nil;
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    urlToDelete = [documentURLs objectAtIndex:row];
    [documentURLs removeObjectAtIndex:row];      
}

...
if (urlToDelete) {
    BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:urlToDelete error:&error);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Rob but I get an warning that is incompatible pointer type sending NSURL to a parameter of type NSString and the file remains

Comment: `NSFileManager` also has a method named `removeItemAtURL:error:`.